# Terraform: remote-exec chose interpreter

Tags: terraform

I want to use /bin/bash instead of the default /bin/sh for ubuntu. How do I set the default interpreter for remote-exec?

I know I can put it as part of a script and then upload the script, but I prefer knowing how to do it in-line in the "best" terraform way.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this ? @lucas-kauffman

Answer (score 0):

This is a gcp exemple but it should remain true for others:

```
metadata_startup_script = <<SCRIPT
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm executing myself at startup"
SCRIPT
```

You declare the start or the script <

Hope this helps.